# How do I build with Maven on github actions and store the python output

Tags: python, maven, github, build, github-actions

I have a repository (protobuf stuff) that I build with Maven and it puts python package in a directory if you install it locally.
I'd like to build this on a push to GitHub and have this directory created or a python package I can pip install from created.
I've been trying GitHub actions but I can't quite figure out that.  Any thoughts?
I'm exploring sub modules next.
Goal is to have python repository always being working with the latest data from this other repository that creates a python package I'm using.

Comment: Question: Why are you building python with Maven?

Comment: Not sure why that's relevant, but i'm using generating google protobuf metadata for both Java and Python.

Comment: This question is too broad. You need to ask a specific question. Where is your POM file? Where are your protobuf files? Do you know how to build python packages? See https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/. How do you generate the protobuf python files? Where is your workflow yaml file? What folder are you generating the python files into?

Comment: @sanewalt The point is Maven is a build tool for Java ..not for python...that the reason why it's relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I do apologize if it was a broad question for you to understand.  But I thought the last sentence was the real problem:   Goal is to have python repository always being working with the latest data from this other repository that creates a python package I'm using.

anyway I solved it using 
https://github.com/ad-m/github-push-action

allows me to push up the new files generated from the Maven build to my Python repository.  This way whenever someone checks in Repository A, the new Python files get pushed to Repository B, after passing tests of course.  Thanks.